# How can I run spring boot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to run PiggyMetrics app which use spring boot framework https://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics
I found multiple ways to run spring boot application here: https://dzone.com/articles/five-ways-of-running-spring-boot-application

but none of these worked with me

there's no option for run it as Spring boot application or java application even in the classes that contains main method

Answer (score 0):

The application you are trying to run is a Microservice Architecture Pattern application using Spring Boot, Spring Cloud and Docker.

So first thing you should have is docker installed on your OS so that you can run all the services parallel.

Here is pictorial presentation.

[image]